# Implement ConQuest score command in TAM

Tags: r, r-lavaan

in the IRT software *ConQuest* you can use the command "score" to model multiple dimensions/latent variables using the same manifest variable/raw data, but different coding. For example:

```
score (1,2,3) (0,1,2) (0,1,0) ! items(1-3);
```

"recodes" the original scores from 1 to 3 in 0, 1, and 2 for the first dimension and to 0, 1, 0 for the second dimension (latent variable).

Do you know any way how to implement the same in the *R package TAM* (using the *lavaan* syntax or otherwise)? I am trying to run a PCM analysis.

Great thanks in advance!

KH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get an answer here, but I contacted Alexander Robitzsch, the author  of the TAM package, and here's what he send me (published with his permission):

```
data(data.gpcm)
psych::describe(data.gpcm)
resp <- data.gpcm

# define three dimensions and different loadings
# of item categories on these dimensions
I <- 3  # 3 items
D <- 3  # 3 dimensions

# define loading matrix B
# 4 categories for each item (0,1,2,3)
B <- array( 0 , dim=c(I,4,D) )
for (ii in 1:I){
    B[ ii , 1:4  , 1 ] <- 0:3
    B[ ii , 1 ,2 ] <- 1
    B[ ii , 4 ,3 ] <- 1
            }
dimnames(B)[[1]] <- colnames(resp)
B[1,,]
  ##   > B[1,,]
  ##        [,1] [,2] [,3]
  ##   [1,]    0    1    0
  ##   [2,]    1    0    0
  ##   [3,]    2    0    0
  ##   [4,]    3    0    1

# test run
mod1 <- tam.mml( resp , B = B , control=list( snodes=1000 , maxiter=5)  )
summary(mod1)
```

I had to edit the code for my needs, of course, but something in particular might be of interest for all of you: For some reason, the B matrix only worked if I had also defined a 0 category, although my ratings/data only included values from 1 to 5:

```
B <- array( 0 , dim=c(9,6,5) ) # 9 items, 5 response cat. + 1, 5 latent dimensions
for (ii in 1:I){
  B[ ii , 1:6  , 1 ] <- 0:5
  B[ ii , 2 ,2 ] <- 1
  B[ ii , 2 ,3 ] <- 1
  B[ ii , 6 ,3 ] <- 1
  B[ ii , 6 ,4 ] <- 1
  B[ ii , 4 ,5 ] <- 1
}

dimnames(B)[[1]] <- colnames(X)
B[1,,]
```

Cheers,
KH

Answer (score 1):

Just as an extension to the above answer with `TAM`, here is how to run the same code with the `mirt` package, except using the generalized partial credit model instead of the Rasch model (Rasch model requires an explicit model argument for proper identification).

```
library(mirt)
gpcm_mats <- list(B[1,,], B[2,,], B[3,,])
sv <- mirt(resp, 3, itemtype = 'gpcm', 
           gpcm_mats = gpcm_mats, pars = 'values') #starting values
mod <- mirt(resp, 3, itemtype = 'gpcm', gpcm_mats = gpcm_mats)
coef(mod, simplify=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, Phil.

Here's the code that I used for my goal of modelling a content as well as response style dimensions:



`library(mirt)
mats <- list()
mats[1:9] <- list(matrix(c(0:4, 1,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,1, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,0,1,0,0), 5))
model <- mirt.model('T = 1-9
                    ARS = 1-9
                    ERS = 1-9
                    DRS = 1-9
                    MRS = 1-9
                    COV = ARS*ERS*DRS*MRS')
mirtModel <- mirt(X, model, 'gpcm', gpcm_mats = mats, method="QMCEM")`

Comment: Note, however, that the gpcm_mats attribute is only implemented in the development version of the mirt package, available at https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt