# Is there a way to simulate a dataset based on a model object in TAM?

Tags: r, simulation

so I've estimated a multidimensional IRT model using the TAM package, based on this dataset that I have.

So now that I have the TAM fit object, is there any way to use it to simulate a new dataset that "abides by the rules" of that model I estimated?

Here is something similar, but about lme fit objects:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11233/how-to-simulate-data-based-on-a-linear-mixed-model-fit-object-in-r

Thanks in advance,
KH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

now, since TAM version 1.10-0, it is possible using the function `IRT.simulate` (see respective help file). Thanks again for the request.

```
library(TAM)
data(data.gpcm)
psych::describe(data.gpcm)
resp <- data.gpcm

# define three dimensions and different loadings of item categories 
# on these dimensions in B loading matrix
I <- 3  # 3 items
D <- 3  # 3 dimensions
# define loading matrix B
# 4 categories for each item (0, 1, 2, 3)
B <- array(0 , dim = c(I, 4, D))
for (ii in 1:I){
  B[ii, 1:4, 1] <- 0:3
  B[ii, 1, 2] <- 1    
  B[ii, 4, 3] <- 1
}
dimnames(B)[[1]] <- colnames(resp)            
B[1, , ]
##   > B[1,,]
##        [,1] [,2] [,3]
##   [1,]    0    1    0
##   [2,]    1    0    0
##   [3,]    2    0    0
##   [4,]    3    0    1
#-- test run
mod1 <- tam.mml(resp, B = B, control = list(snodes = 1000, maxiter = 5))

sim.dat <- IRT.simulate(mod1, nobs = 2000)
```

### Old Solution

I wouldn't say it is impossible. However, for the time being, it is not *easy* since it involves handling of `TAM` internal functions and attributes of the estimation object. That is, there is no method yet that lets you extract the response probability function at prespecified trait points.

**However, thanks to your request, we are working on exactly this very valuable feature and I'll give an update to this answer as soon as the method is on CRAN.**

For now, let's extend the example of that request: [Implement ConQuest score command in TAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809052/implement-conquest-score-command-in-tam) that Alex also included at the manual page of the `tam` function as `EXAMPLE 20`.

```
data(data.gpcm)
psych::describe(data.gpcm)
resp <- data.gpcm

# define three dimensions and different loadings of item categories 
# on these dimensions in B loading matrix
I <- 3  # 3 items
D <- 3  # 3 dimensions
# define loading matrix B
# 4 categories for each item (0, 1, 2, 3)
B <- array(0 , dim = c(I, 4, D))
for (ii in 1:I){
  B[ii, 1:4, 1] <- 0:3
  B[ii, 1, 2] <- 1    
  B[ii, 4, 3] <- 1
}
dimnames(B)[[1]] <- colnames(resp)            
B[1, , ]
##   > B[1,,]
##        [,1] [,2] [,3]
##   [1,]    0    1    0
##   [2,]    1    0    0
##   [3,]    2    0    0
##   [4,]    3    0    1
#-- test run
mod1 <- tam.mml(resp, B = B, control = list(snodes = 1000, maxiter = 5))
```

Now for the part where we extract the attributes that are necessary for the computation of the response probabilities and generate new testees.

```
# Extract necessary item attributes
xsi <- mod1$xsi$xsi
A <- mod1$A
B <- mod1$B
maxK <- mod1$maxK

nI <- dim(A)[1]
iIndex <- 1:nI
AXsi <- matrix(0, nrow = nI, ncol = maxK)

# Simulate new testees
nnodes <- 2000
theta <- mvrnorm(n = nnodes, mod1$beta, mod1$variance)
```

The response probabilities can be obtained from a call to an internal function.

```
# Calculate response probablities and simulate
p <- TAM:::calc_prob.v5(iIndex, A, AXsi, B, xsi, theta, nnodes, maxK, recalc = TRUE)$rprobs 
p[,,1] # response probability of testee 1 to each category 0, 1, 2, 3 for all three items
#            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.06738066 0.8111365 0.1043441 0.0171387
# [2,] 0.02545206 0.4895568 0.3182046 0.1667866
# [3,] 0.04503185 0.5105446 0.3429603 0.1014633
```

With this, simulate the success cut and compare that to the response probabilities.

```
sim.data <- matrix(runif(nnodes * nI), nrow = nnodes, ncol = nI)
for(pp in 1:nnodes){
  cat.success.pp <- (sim.data[pp, ] > t(apply(p[, , pp], 1, cumsum)))
  sim.data[pp, ] <-  c(cat.success.pp %*% rep(1, maxK))
}
```

Best,
Tom